# Changing log to 'DEBUG' level doesn't output to console like it did before I changed it to 'WARNING; in Pythons Logging module

Tags: python, logging

I am using the following code within a class to initiate a logger in Python.

```
...
    self.logger_name=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'HMM.log')
    self.logger=self._get_logger()  
    self.initial_log()


def _get_logger(self):
    childLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    childLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    cname=self.logger_name[:-4]+ now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") +'.log'
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s:  %(message)s')
    childHandler=logging.FileHandler(cname,mode='w')
    childHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    childLogger.addHandler(childHandler)
    childLogger.propagate = True
    return childLogger       

...
```

The level was set to `logging.DEBUG` (second line down in `_get_logger()`) and worked fine, (i.e. printed the log to the console as well as to file). I then changed it to `logging.WARNING` for a little while. Now that I want to change it back I no longer get a this information printed to console and only to file. Can anybody tell me why this has happened?